# How to get the string like this remove repeating in String Java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am sending the arrays from jquery to controller, and this arrays I am getting as String in controller `String getIdVal = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "getId");`
The Values in `String getIds` are like `getIdVal ="1_ABC,2_ABC,3_ABC,4_NMO,5_NMO,6_XYZ"`;

I am trying to get the result but no successes.
(Considering `1 is key ABC is value)`.
I wanted to remove ABC(ie repeated values) from all keys and append only once at the end. And at the same time I want the keys of repeated values should be like this `(1-2-3_ABC)`.
 Finally the String should look like this `"1-2-3_ABC,4-5_NMO,6_XYZ"`

here I am try8ing to split based on comma, but I dont know how to solve.

```
 List<String> keysVals = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getIdVal .split(",")));
                String getKeyVal;
                String[] getKeys;
                String key;
                String value;
    for (String getKeysVals : keysVals) {
        getKeyVal = getKeysVals;
        getKeys = getKeyVal.split("\\_");
        key = getKeys[0];
        value = getKeyVal.substring(getKeyVal.lastIndexOf("_") + 1) .trim();
        // i am not getting how to check for dublicate
        }
```

Comment: What is logic behind `4_NMO,5_NMO` becoming `1-2_NMO`, but `6_XYZ` becoming `5_XYZ`?

Comment: The logic does not even make sense.

Comment: Sorry Brothers, its typo,I have made it correct

Comment: @Khusboo Ok I check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
private static String mergeKeys(String input) {
    Map<String, StringBuilder> valKeys = new TreeMap<>();
    if (! input.isEmpty())
        for (String keyVal : input.split(",")) {
            int idx = keyVal.indexOf('_');
            String key = keyVal.substring(0, idx);
            String val = keyVal.substring(idx + 1);
            StringBuilder builder = valKeys.get(val);
            if (builder == null)
                valKeys.put(val, new StringBuilder(key));
            else
                builder.append('-').append(key);
        }
    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(",");
    for (Entry<String, StringBuilder> entry : valKeys.entrySet())
        result.add(entry.getValue().append('_').append(entry.getKey()).toString());
    return result.toString();
}
```

Or this slow version of the same logic, using `string = string + string` *(Yikes!)*:

```
private static String mergeKeys(String input) {
    Map<String, String> valKeys = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    if (! input.isEmpty())
        for (String keyVal : input.split(",")) {
            int idx = keyVal.indexOf('_');
            String key = keyVal.substring(0, idx);
            String val = keyVal.substring(idx + 1);
            String prevKeys = valKeys.get(val);
            valKeys.put(val, prevKeys == null ? key : prevKeys + "-" + key);
        }
    String result = "";
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : valKeys.entrySet())
        result += "," + entry.getValue() + "_" + entry.getKey();
    return result.substring(1); // skip leading comma
}
```

**TEST**

```
System.out.println(mergeKeys("1_ABC,2_ABC,3_ABC,4_NMO,5_NMO,6_XYZ"));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1-2-3_ABC,4-5_NMO,6_XYZ
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks a lot, you answer is  awesome  :)